# simple feature toggle in xamarin forms - error converting string to page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use the following in Xamarin Forms to set the login page based on whether in debug mode or not, like a feature toggle.

I store the 2 page names I want as strings in a .resx resource file, but I get an error because it cannot convert from the string returned to a xamarin.forms page.

Even if I alter the static string to static xamarin.forms.page it will still error as the resx returns a string.

Is there any way round this so I can use this?

```
public static string StartUpPage
        {
            get
            {
#if DEBUG
                return Resources.Redirects.SwipeFeatureOff;
#else
                return Resources.Redirects.SwipeFeatureOn;
#endif
            }
        }
```

Usage:

```
var _page = Agronomy.Config.AppConfig.StartUpPage;
NavigationPage page = new NavigationPage(_page);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a instance via `Activator.CreateInstance` after obtaining the type of your string via `Type.GetType`:

```
// fully qualify your string (namespace . classname)
var _pageString = Agronomy.Config.AppConfig.StartUpPage;
var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(_pageString));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and what you say makes sense, though I do get a 'value cannot be null' error on the 2nd line of your code, I'm assuming the string in my resx must include ".xaml"?

Comment: @DarkW1nter Your "string" needs to be fully qualified (namespaceName + "." + className) OR use `Activator.CreateInstance(namespace, classname)`, you still need the namespace, but in that case you can hardcode the namespace and keep the classname in your `Resources....`

Comment: Went with namespace+className in the resources - now get a 'specified cast not valid' on same line as before (appreciate the help here by the way)

Comment: @DarkW1nter Replace the `NavigationPage`  cast with the actual type of `Page` that the class is (i.e. `ContentPage`, etc... )